# How can I find a program for selecting in "open with..."

Tags: openoffice.org

I wanted to install an extension for OpenOffice. After downloading the extension (an .oxt file), Firefox asked me how do I want to open it. It gave me two options: LibreOffice or Other. So I selected Other, but then I had no clue, how to find Open Office.

I went to /usr/bin but saw no clue of open office. I tried "which openoffice" - no reply. "which writer" - no reply.

Finally I had an idea - I opened OpenOffice and did "ps -ecf|grep open". I found it in "/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice.bin".

Is there a better way to locate a program on my computer?

Comment: Did you tried at properties "open with" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After choosing "other application", at the resultant window you must click the bar near the bottom marked "show other applications". I understand your frustration. Ubuntu is ordinarily so sensible that one simply would not expect it to need you to ask to be shown the other applications you might want to select from. After the other options are shown to you, you should be able to find OpenOffice. Once it has been opened this way, it should appear in the menu when you right-click on such a file.